# Supervised Extractive Text Summarization

Tags: python, keras, nlp, nltk, text-extraction

I want to extract potential sentences from news articles which can be part of article summary.

Upon spending some time, I found out that this can be achieved in two ways,

1. Extractive Summarization (Extracting sentences from text and clubbing them)
2. Abstractive Summarization (internal language representation to generate more human-like summaries)

Reference: [rare-technologies.com](https://rare-technologies.com/text-summarization-in-python-extractive-vs-abstractive-techniques-revisited/)

I followed [abigailsee's Get To The Point: Summarization with Pointer-Generator Networks](http://www.abigailsee.com/2017/04/16/taming-rnns-for-better-summarization.html) for summarization which was producing good results with the pre-trained model but it was abstractive.

**The Problem:**
Most of the extractive summarizers that I have looked so far(PyTeaser, PyTextRank and Gensim) are not based on Supervised learning but on Naive Bayes classifier, tf–idf, POS-tagging, sentence ranking based on keyword-frequency, position etc., which don't require any training.

Few things that I have tried so far to extract potential summary sentences.

- Get all sentences of articles and label summary sentences as 1 and 0 for all others
- Clean up the text and apply stop word filters
- Vectorize a text corpus using Tokenizer `from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer` with Vocabulary size of 20000 and pad all sequences to average length of all sentences.
- Build a Sqequential keras model a train it.

```py
model_lstm = Sequential()
model_lstm.add(Embedding(20000, 100, input_length=sentence_avg_length))
model_lstm.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model_lstm.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model_lstm.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is giving very low accuracy ~0.2

I think this is because the above model is more suitable for positive/negative sentences rather than summary/non-summary sentences classification.

Any guidance on approach to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps to extract the keytopics & use those sentences which mention them to generate the summary -> https://tech.goibibo.com/key-topics-extraction-and-contextual-sentiment-of-users-reviews-20e63c0fd7ca

Answer (score 1):

> I think this is because the above model is more suitable for
>   positive/negative sentences rather than summary/non-summary sentences
>   classification.

That's right. The above model is used for binary classification, not text summarization. If you notice, the output (`Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`) only gives you a score between 0-1 while in text summarization we need a model that generates a sequence of tokens.

*What should I do?*

The dominant idea to tackle this problem is [encoder-decoder](https://machinelearningmastery.com/encoder-decoder-deep-learning-models-text-summarization/) (also known as seq2seq) models. There is a [nice tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) on Keras repository which used for Machine translation but it is fairly easy to adapt it for text summarization.

The main part of the code is:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense

# Define an input sequence and process it.
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the 
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

# Run training
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2)
```

Based on the above implementation, it is necessary to pass `encoder_input_data`, `decoder_input_data` and `decoder_target_data` to `model.fit()` which respectively are input text and summarize version of the text.

Note that, `decoder_input_data` and `decoder_target_data` are the same things except that `decoder_target_data` is one token ahead of `decoder_input_data`.

> This is giving very low accuracy ~0.2
>
> I think this is because the above model is more suitable for
>   positive/negative sentences rather than summary/non-summary sentences
>   classification.

The low accuracy performance caused by various reasons including small training size, overfitting, underfitting and etc.

Comment: But this is again an abstractive summarization model which takes a text as input, encodes it and decoder generates an abstractive summary. I have tried abigailsee's model which kind of does the same. What I am trying to solve is given a text as input (most likely represented in vector form)  return the sentences(belonging to the original text) or indexes of sentences in the text that can be part of summary.

Comment: @UserX See [here](https://github.com/jatinarora2702/Research-Text-Summarization) for an extractive example

Comment: I am not sure why the author of the [link](https://github.com/jatinarora2702/Research-Text-Summarization) named it as "System for extractive summarization of research text using Deep Learning" but it is just feeding extractive summaries from Lex-Rank and other unsupervised models as training data to three abstarctive approaches.